# What versions of Java can Grails 4.X run with?

Tags: java, grails, java-14

I have read the Grails 4.X documentation that doesn't seem to indicate the versions of Java that it would work with, except to say it no longer works with java 7.

> Before installing Grails 4.0.3 you will need as a minimum a Java Development Kit (JDK) installed version 1.8 or above.

-- http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html

I am running with 14.0.1+7 installed on my mac using sdk-man. When I try to build an existing grails project, or create a new project, it fails with an error.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Install jdk 14 using sdk-man `sdk install java 14.0.1-open`
2. Install Grails `sdk install grails 4.0.3`
3. Create Grails project `grails create-app MyApp`
4. Results

```
$ grails create-app testJDK14
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
        at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
        at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
        at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
```

I found a [related issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10248) with jdk 14 and gradle 5.1.1 that Grails ships with that recommends upgrading gradle to 6.3+. It was not specific to Grails.

So I upgraded gradle in my Grails project using the gradle-wrapper.properties file, but still receive the same, although that cleared it for many using Gradle, but not Grails.

Is there a list of JDKs that is known to work with Grails 4.X?

Comment: Switch to Java 8. Java 9 introduced a module system that broke backward compatibility unexpectedly to many projects. If you see something saying use Java 8 or above, stick to Java 8; unless you find something indicating **explicitly** that it supports some other version. Grails needs [Groovy 2.5](https://groovy-lang.org/install.html) and that *There are currently some known issues for some aspects when using Java 9 snapshots.*

Comment: I've tried java 11 as well now, with the same error. I'm happy to stay with Java 8, but I am wondering if there is some official recommendation from Graeme or the Grails project. Maybe it would be better for their documentation to just say Java 8, instead of Java 8+.

Comment: I agree. It would be better if their documentation was updated.

Comment: Do you know if it would be considered a bug? If it is, I could log an issue with the Github issue tracker. I started that, and it recommended asking a question here first.

Comment: I should say, part of the reason I want to upgrade the JDK is that I want to take advantage of the Docker memory capabilities added after 10. https://medium.com/adorsys/usecontainersupport-to-the-rescue-e77d6cfea712, although I see it was backported to 8u191, so maybe I'm in the clear.

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10323

Answer (score 4):

JDK14 which is not supported by grails 4.0.x. Use a LTS version such as Java 11 or 8. wait until grails updates to the latest

Spring-boot, which Grails is based on, [added support for JDK 14](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/26/spring-boot-2-2-6-available-now) recently. JDK 14 will likely be supported in Grails 4.1.x series.

Comment: I did try 11, and encountered the same issue.

Comment: There may be something wrong with your local install then, I just verified it does work using 11.0.7.

Comment: I just tried again. You are right, it does run, albeit with a warning:
```
$ grails create-app MyApp
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/a510523/work/software/grails-4.0.1/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-2.5.6.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
...
```

Comment: So, then, to answer my question
> Is there a list of JDKs that is known to work with Grails 4.X?
You mention JDK14 is not supported by Grails. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Grails 4.0.x is based on Spring-Boot 2.1.x which does not support JDK14. The reference is spring-boots documentation in the link above.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your patience with me @erichelgeson. Since the error is around groovy, it doesn't seem to directly obvious that Grails 4.1.X would support that. I agree it seems possible, but it would be difficult to make any plans on that. A reference from Grails documentation would  be something we could make plans on. Have you see a note from Grails that has
> a list of JDKs that is known to work with Grails 4.X?

Comment: E.g. the latest release said http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew it supports 2.2.3, but jdk 14 is 2.2.6, so I can't tell if/where it is in the roadmap, per se.

Comment: The master branch has the latest 2.2.x in it - so will be in the next Milestone.